# How does @ModelAttribute work in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model

I'm learning about Spring framework and I thought that when we're using the `@ModelAttribute` in the controller we need to specify this ModelAttribute in the jsp too. And here is an example:

The controller:

```
@PostMapping("/processRegistrationForm")
public String processRegistrationForm(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("crmUser") CrmUser theCrmUser, 
        BindingResult theBindingResult, 
        Model theModel) {

            ...
     }
```

The jsp:

```
                <!-- Registration Form -->
                <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register/processRegistrationForm" 
                           modelAttribute="crmUser"
                           class="form-horizontal">

                    <!-- User name -->
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 
                        <form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" />
                        <form:input path="userName" placeholder="username (*)" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    ...........

                </form:form>
```

So we've specified the modelAttribute in the jsp `modelAttribute="crmUser"`.

But here is another example of using @ModelAttribute and there is no specification about this modelAttribute in the jsp. And it works perfectly.

The Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/registerUser")
public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "login/login";

}
```

The jsp:

```
<form action="registerUser" method="post">
    <pre>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
        Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
        User Name: <input type="text" name="email"/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassword"/>
        <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </pre>
</form>
```

So in this situation we don't specify the modelAttribute in the jsp. And I can't understand how does Spring know who is the Model. Is user a default name for the modelAttribute and we specify the modelAttribute in the jsp only when we use another name? Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually specify it in your form

```
@PostMapping("/registerUser")
public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "login/login";

}
```

Using spring form tag

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/registerUser"
  modelAttribute="user">...
```

If you dont specify Spring might do it on your behind as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation

... and you dont need to specify it because as with the rest endpoints, at this resource mappings, you can have only one body, in this case, is your form object.